# Transit Visa from Peru to Italy

Tags: visas, uk, transit, italy, peruvian-citizens

I am traveling from Peru to Italy via London Heathrow on August 25. I will be at LHR on 26 August at 2 pm and departing at 8 pm. I'm an Peruvian national and have a valid Schengen student visa.

Do I need a transit visa to stay airside?

I have been scared that British Airways have stopped a few people from boarding flights (no details just rumors).

Do I need a transit visa to stay landside? I want to do some sightseeing. What are the chances of getting past officials using transit without visa concession?

Comment: Can you detail exactly what visa you have, as that may make a large difference. (What country issued it, how long it is valid for, what Schengen type it is etc)

Comment: @Gagravarr Would not matter in this case since the OP is a Peruvian national. Also, it would be safe to assume that a student visa is either a long stay Category 'D' visa or a Residence Permit, which would both quality eitherway.

Answer (score 3):

As a Peruvian Citizen, you do not need a visa if you do not enter the UK i.e for an airside transit. This is clearly mentioned on the [Gov.UK website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/peru/transit/no).

On the other hand if you do decide to go land side, then you may be eligible for the [transit without visa concession](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/peru/transit/yes).

> You might be eligible for the ‘transit without visa concession’ if:
>   - you arrive and depart by air
>   - have a confirmed onward flight which leaves within 24 hours
>   - have the correct documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)

The keyword here to note is **may**. Now ideally if all those conditions are met and the immigration official does not see any malicious intent, I don't foresee a problem. In your case it seems that those conditions are met fine, **so you should be able to transit without a visa in either case.**

Answer (score 1):

if you arrive at Heathrow and continue your flight also at Heathrow, you won't have a Problem. Make sure that you Need not to Change the Airport. Sometimes the fligts arrive at Heathrow and continue on an other Airport like Stanstedt. Then you Need a Transfer visa because you are entering UK to go to the next Airport